# Не срабатывает setTimeout в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Здравствуйте, господа!
Возникла проблема следующего характера.
Никак не хочет срабатывать setTimeout в коде:

```
    <script>
    var the_timer, x_position = 0, the_image;
    function set_timer() {
        the_image = document.getElementById("myImg");
        x_position = x_position+1;
        the_image.style.left = x_position;
        the_timer = setTimeout(set_timer, 50);
    };
</script>
</head>
<body onload="set_timer()">
<img id="myImg" src="img.jpg" style="position:absolute; left:0">
</body>
```

По идее картинка должна каждые 50мс двигаться на 1пиксель вправо, но этого не происходит. Никак не могу понять где загвоздка. Консоль в браузере ошибок не выдает, просто скрипт не работает. Возможно, кто-то заметил ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы нигде не вызываете вашу функцию `set_timer` 
Вам бы ее вызвать в конце вашего кода.

```
set_timer();
```

Но у вас какое то зацикливание получается, вам строку `setTimeout(set_timer, 50);`
надо вызывать вне вашей функции.

**update**

```
<script>
    var the_timer, x_position = 0, the_image;
    function set_timer() {
        the_image = document.getElementById("myImg");
        x_position = x_position + 1;
        the_image.style.left = x_position + "px"; //нужно было дописать px

        //console.log(the_image.style.left);
        console.log(x_position);

        the_timer = setTimeout(set_timer, 50);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Если вызвать  `set_timer();` после кода то вылезет ошибка в консоли
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null.
А если вынести `the_timer = setTimeout(set_timer, 50);` за пределы функции то ничего не происходит.
Зацыкливание и должно быть так как картинка должна постоянно перемещаться вправо с задержкой 50мс.

Comment: Какой браузер? `the_image` у вас нулевой, потому что ваш код не нашел картинку по его айдишнику

Comment: Тестировал в Хроме последнем и Опере. Картинка отображается в каждом браузере, но стоит на месте.

Comment: для того чтобы убедиться в запуске вашей функции вам надо просто написать внутри нее например `alert('функция сработала');` или `console.log('проверка');` и смотреть что происходит в консоли

Comment: я не юзаю чистый JS пользуюсь обычно jQuery, надо смотреть что возвращается вызовом `the_image = document.getElementById("myImg");` например написав ниже `console.log(the_image);`

Comment: внес `console.log('проверка');`. Функция вызывается постоянно, Количество "проверок" постоянно растет, что говорит о работе цикла. Но картинка стоит на месте.

Comment: она стоит на месте потому что у вас скорее всего не меняется свойство left
пропишите `console.log(the_image.style.left);`

Comment: если внести `console.log(the_image);` вне функции, то возвращает undefined.

Comment: естественно внутри

Comment: если внутри прописать `console.log(the_image);`, то выдает парметры картинки `img id="myImg" src="img.jpg" style="position:absolute; left:0"`. Если прописать `console.log(the_image.style.left);` то выдает 0px. Хм, следовательно у меня почему-то не работает сдвиг на 1 единицу.

Comment: если помог разобраться, не забудьте отметить мой ответ перед уходом )

Comment: Обязательно отмечу, но проблема так и не решилась)

Comment: смотрите мой ответ выше, там я добавил строчку отладки `console.log(x_position);` что она выдает? она увеличивается?

Comment: Да, в консоли отображается постоянно растущее число x_position, но хоть убейте картинку это не двигает :(

Comment: значит строка `the_image.style.left = x_position;` не работает!

Comment: Возможно как-то указать x_position не просто значение, а значение с px?

Comment: Сработало, дописал `+ "px"` к x_position)) Спасибо большое, что помогли)